# Python 3.11 - creating a virtual Env - Frozen runpy

Tags: linux, python-venv, rhel7, python-3.11

After following a thread on how to fix the pip SLL issue, now this:
So far I have spent more time fixing environments than actual training.

I am using an Oracle appliance with Linux server 7 on it.

Has anyone seen this error and know a fix for it, please?

```
[oracle@localhost myProjects]$ python3 -V
Python 3.11.0a4
[oracle@localhost myProjects]$ python3 -m venv env
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 189, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 148, in _get_module_details
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 112, in _get_module_details
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/venv/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    import logging
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/logging/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sys, os, time, io, re, traceback, warnings, weakref, collections.abc
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/re/__init__.py", line 125, in <module>
    from . import _compiler, _parser
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/re/_compiler.py", line 18, in <module>
    assert _sre.MAGIC == MAGIC, "SRE module mismatch"
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AssertionError: SRE module mismatch
```